# Seaborn saving plots with gray background when it should be white

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

When I save a figure to .png, it saves with an unexpected gray background instead of white.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import random

sns.set_theme()
sns.set_style("whitegrid")
sns.set_context("poster", font_scale=1.8)

xvals = list(range(15,41))
yvals = random.sample(range(0, 50), len(xvals))

sns.set_theme()
sns.set_style("whitegrid")
sns.set_context("poster", font_scale=1.8)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = sns.lineplot(x=xvals, y=yvals)
plt.suptitle('Sample Plot')
ax.set_xlabel('x unit')
ax.set_ylabel('y unit')
ax.autoscale(enable=True, axis='y', tight=True)
fig.savefig('Results/Sample Plot.png', dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
```

The resulting figure saved as png:
[image: Figure with gray background]

What Spyder shows it looking like, and what I'm expecting to save:
[image: Figure with white background]

Comment: try passing the `ax` parameter to `lineplot`

Comment: @PaulH unfortunately that does not work. `fig` has no axes, so there is nothing to pass in. `fig.get_axes()`
`[]`

Comment: Fixed it by passing `facecolor='w'` to savefig

Comment: You need to create the Axes object first. I like to use `fig, ax = plt.subplots()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `facecolor` in figure to specify the background color, like `fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8), dpi=300, facecolor='#FFF')` when you save the plot you can use it again like that `fig.savefig(....,facecolor=fig.get_facecolor())`

## Your code fixed

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import random

sns.set_theme()
sns.set_style("whitegrid")
sns.set_context("poster", font_scale=1.8)

xvals = list(range(15,41))
yvals = random.sample(range(0, 50), len(xvals))

sns.set_theme()
sns.set_style("whitegrid")
sns.set_context("poster", font_scale=1.8)

fig = plt.figure(facecolor='#FFF')
ax = sns.lineplot(x=xvals, y=yvals)
plt.suptitle('Sample Plot')
ax.set_xlabel('x unit')
ax.set_ylabel('y unit')
ax.autoscale(enable=True, axis='y', tight=True)
fig.savefig('Sample Plot.png', dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0,facecolor=fig.get_facecolor())
```